# Extract one colour channel from 4-dimensional cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working with OpenCV for a while and experiment with the DNN extension. My model has the input shape [1, 3, 224, 244] with pixel-depth uint8. So I put my m_inputImg which has 3-channels and 8 bit pixel depth in the function:

```
cv::dnn::blobFromImage(m_inputImg, m_inputImgTensor, 1.0, cv::Size(), cv::Scalar(), false, false, CV_8U);
```

Now I'm interested in having a Idea how my input image "lay" inside the cv::Mat tensor. Theoretically I know how the tensor looks like, but I don't understand how OpenCV do it. So to understand this I want to extract one colour channel. I've tried this:

```
cv::Mat blueImg  = cv::Mat(cp->getModelConfigs().model[0].input.height,
                            cp->getModelConfigs().model[0].input.width,
                            CV_8UC3,
                            blob.ptr<uint8_t>(0, 0);
```

But what I get is something like that (see picture). I'm realy confused about that, can anybody help or has a good advice?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: How does your original image look like? If you only want to display 1 channel, why are you using CV_8UC3 imho you are currently displaying the whole tensor as BGRBGRBGR... but your data should be arranged RRR...GGG...BBB... can you try just using CV_8UC1? Imho then you should get the RRR... image. But I'm not sure why there are 9 images in your blob.

Comment: In your blob creating shouldnt it be cv::Size(224,224) instead of cv::Size()?

Comment: When I try CV_8UC1 i will get just noise in my image, so my pointer might be show in undefined regions.

Comment: For the size Parameter OpenCV write this: "size: spatial size for output image". So in my opinion cv::Size(224, 224) is wrong, because the output "image" is the tensor. But I have no idea what size should be used, so I let this by default (maybe OpenCV know's what I want... :D)

Comment: In your image, the first 1/3 of the image is the first channel of the blob. Since you are interpreting the mono blob channel as a 3 channel image, it will read the second line of the image after 1/3 of the displayed image and the third line at 2/3 of the displayed image. Because you are reading more lines than desired, the second channel starts at 1/3 of the displayed images rows and the third channel starts at 2/3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cv::Size() will use the original image size. You are interpreting the data wrong. Here are 4 ways to interpret a 512x512 (`cv::Size()`) loaded blob-start from the lenna image:

input (512x512):

[image]

1. blob-start as a 512x512 single channel image:

[image]

2. blob-start as a 512x512 BGR image:

[image]

3. blob-start as a 224x224 BGR image:

[image]

4. blob-start as a 224x224 single channel:

[image]

here's the code:

```
int main()
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("C:/data/Lenna.png"); // 8UC3
    cv::imshow("img", img);


    cv::Mat blob;
    cv::dnn::blobFromImage(img, blob, 1.0, cv::Size(), cv::Scalar(), false, false, CV_8U);

    cv::Mat redImg = cv::Mat(img.rows,
        img.cols,
        CV_8UC1,
        blob.ptr<uint8_t>(0, 0));

    cv::imshow("blob 1", redImg);
    cv::imwrite("red1.jpg", redImg);

    cv::Mat redImg3C = cv::Mat(img.rows,
        img.cols,
        CV_8UC3,
        blob.ptr<uint8_t>(0, 0));

    cv::imshow("redImg3C", redImg3C);
    cv::imwrite("red3C.jpg", redImg3C);

    cv::Mat redImg224_3C = cv::Mat(224,
        224,
        CV_8UC3,
        blob.ptr<uint8_t>(0, 0));

    cv::imshow("redImg224_3C", redImg224_3C);
    cv::imwrite("redImg224_3C.jpg", redImg224_3C);

    cv::Mat redImg224_1C = cv::Mat(224,
        224,
        CV_8UC1,
        blob.ptr<uint8_t>(0, 0));

    cv::imshow("redImg224_1C", redImg224_1C);
    cv::imwrite("redImg224_1C.jpg", redImg224_1C);
    

    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

Imho you have to do in your code:

```
cv::dnn::blobFromImage(m_inputImg, blob, 1.0, cv::Size(), cv::Scalar(), false, false, CV_8U);

cv::Mat blueImg  = cv::Mat(m_inputImg.rows,
                        m_inputImg.cols,
                        CV_8UC3,
                        blob.ptr<uint8_t>(0, 0);
```

OR

```
cv::dnn::blobFromImage(m_inputImg, blob, 1.0, cv::Size(cp->getModelConfigs().model[0].input.width , cp->getModelConfigs().model[0].input.height), cv::Scalar(), false, false, CV_8U);

cv::Mat blueImg  = cv::Mat(cp->getModelConfigs().model[0].input.height,
                        cp->getModelConfigs().model[0].input.width,
                        CV_8UC3,
                        blob.ptr<uint8_t>(0, 0);
```

In addition, here's the version of setting the spatial blob image size to a fixed size (e.g. the desired DNN input size):

```
    cv::Mat blob2;
    cv::dnn::blobFromImage(img, blob2, 1.0, cv::Size(224,224), cv::Scalar(), false, false, CV_8U);

    cv::Mat blueImg224_1C = cv::Mat(224,
        224,
        CV_8UC1,
        blob2.ptr<uint8_t>(0, 0));

    cv::imshow("blueImg224_1C", blueImg224_1C);
    cv::imwrite("blueImg224_1C.jpg", blueImg224_1C);
```

Giving this image:
[image]

Comment: there is a mistake in the sample. This is not the RED channel, since I didnt swap the channels during blobFromImage. Instead it is the BLUE channel, but still the basic message is the same.

Comment: I think I understand this a little bit more. But in your edit, you provide a sample for extracting the "BLUE" channel, but in the result image it seems to be easily the grayscaled image from the original image.

Comment: drawing a single channel is always gray. If you want to display it as a color image, you will have to merge a single channel with 2 empty channels. Like: `std::vector<cv::Mat> bgrMerger; bgrMerger.push_back(blueMat); bgrMerger.push_back(emptyMat);  bgrMerger.push_back(emptyMat);` then `cv::merge(bgrMerger, bgrImage);` and `cv::imshow("image", bgrImage);`

Comment: Yes your're right. But in my opinion only pixels with a value >0 in the blue channel will be shown. It seems to be different when I have a look at your sample image.